custom allocator to std::map that allocates objects, while the map iterates over pointers
I need to limit the capacity an prevent dynamic allocations of an std::map, using a company-internal implementation of a pool container. Let us consider the following dummy class:
class A{
    public:
    A():classData(count++){std::cout<<"In A constructor()"<<std::endl;}
    int classData;
    inline static int count = 0;
};

This class only promotes the classData in each instantiation, such that it is easy to follow them. I tried to define the following allocator:
template <typename T, typename OBJ = void>
class CustomAllocator {
public:
    using value_type = T;
    using OBJ_VAL = std::remove_pointer_t<OBJ>;
   
    CustomAllocator() = default;
 
    template <typename U>
    constexpr CustomAllocator(const CustomAllocator<U>&) noexcept {}
 
    [[nodiscard]] T* allocate(std::size_t n) {
        if (n > std::size_t(-1) / sizeof(T)){
            throw std::bad_alloc();
        }     
        if (auto p = static_cast<T*>(std::malloc(n * sizeof(T)))) {
            std::cout << "Allocated " << n * sizeof(T) << " bytes"<<std::endl;
            return p;
        }
        throw std::bad_alloc();
    }
 
    void deallocate(T* p, std::size_t n) noexcept {
        std::cout << "Deallocated " << n * sizeof(T) << " bytes\n";
        std::free(p);
    }
 
    template <typename U, typename... Args>
    void construct(U* p, Args&&... args) {
            new(p) T();
            A*& tmp = ((U&)(*p)).second;
            tmp = &dataArr[i++];
    }
 
    template <typename U>
    void destroy(U* p) noexcept {
        p->~U();
    }
    std::atomic_int i = 0;
 
 
    std::array<A, 3> dataArr;
};

Usually, the allocator is supposed to be templated on an std::pair<const key,obj>, however, in my case the requirement is that the iterator of the map returns pointers to the objects and not the objects themselves. What I tried (failed) to do here, is make the allocator allocate the object into the array, and fill the map with pointers. The array represents the company-internal data structure I am trying to use. This allocator can create an object using a method allocObj(), and destroy one using freeObj(obj) (obj is a pointer to the object).
I am not sure this is the correct approach at all. I thought about somehow tickling with the return type of the iterator, but I don't know how it is possible to achieve this.
This is my code, trying to use CustomAllocator as an allocator for an std::map:
template <typename T, typename U>
using CustomAllocMap = std::map<T, U, std::less<T>, CustomAllocator<std::pair<const T, U>, U>>;
 
int main() {
    // Create a map using the custom allocator, with pointers as the objects in the class
    CustomAllocMap<int, A*> customMap;
   
    customMap[1];
    std::cout<<"Created first"<<std::endl;
    customMap[2];
    std::cout<<"Created second"<<std::endl;
    customMap[3];
    std::cout<<"Created third"<<std::endl;
 
    for (const auto& pair : customMap) {
        std::cout << pair.first << ": " << pair.second->classData << '\n';
    }
 
    return 0;
}

So, to sum up the question, how do I make an std::map, that returns pointers to the objects and not the objects themselves when iterated. At the same time, the map's capacity is limited using a specific data structure that is responsible for the memory allocation?

The deleted question: Implementatino of custom allocator for std::map, so that the iterrator will return pointers to objects

You should edit your original question rather than deleting the original and posting a new one

the comments on the previous question might be useful and are now lost

@PepijnKramer that's the idea of a custom allocator. It will manage the allocations of the map itself.

So, TL;DR, you just want to have SomeMap<int, A*> that (when you call customMap[1];) instead of inserting nullptr, must allocate new A on your datapool and return a pointer to newly created object?

@pptaszni, I think you summed it up pretty well. Though, another solution that answers my requirements is also good.

They're lost to most people who can't see deleted questions

The allocator should be implemented as a handle to a memory resource, which is the std::array container in this case, not as a wrapper around the memory resource itself.
